# Prompting for slot in Watson without storing in context variable

Tags: watson-conversation, watson

Is there any way to build Watson conversation in such a way that it always prompts for a slot but the value is not saved in context variable?

For Eg:- I want to retrieve details of a particular employee.

So the query will be like "***details for employee 123***" where 123 is employee id.

If I ask "***employee details***", bot should prompt me for employee id. It should not take the previous context value.

Is there any solution to achieve this? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

use slot with @sys-number or employee id entity so that if it is not mentioned in input then it will be promoted again.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a bit late, but you can always delete the content of the variable after executing the query. To do so, just go in the context editor and make a variable with a name you won't ever use. Then set it to `<? context.remove('employee id') ?>` (or the exact name of your variable. If necessary, make this into a child node after sending the query to make sure that the variable is cleared only after you aready did what you needed on it.